# two owners for the same XIB file

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I have a XIB file with a view, this view is a header for the a tableview. Currently the owner of this file is the ViewController that contains the tableview, and the main view of the xib is linked with the property called myViewFromMyXIB

In viewDidLoad method, I load the view with this method:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXIB" owner:self options:nil];
self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = self.myViewFromMyXIB;
```

Now, I have another ViewController with other tableView, but I need use the same header,

I know that I could load the view in this way:

```
NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXIB"
                                              owner:self
                                            options:nil];

UIView* myView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];

self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = myView;
```

But I think this way is not very clean, are there any way to set two owners in a XIB?

Thanksssss!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have developed which I wrote before:

```
NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXIB"
                                          owner:self
                                        options:nil];

UIView* myView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
```

self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = myView;

The iOS Developer Library doesn´t tell another different way:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW25